# Any click after clicking my richTextBox changing the size back to normal

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, richtextbox

When I click in my richTextBox, I run this code to make my textbox bigger for the user:

```
this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 100);
```

Now I want any click after clicking my richTextBox to change the size back to the original:

```
 this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(477, 26);
```

I can use the code above for each element mouse click event, but I am wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the first code in `richtextbox.enter` event. And the second in `richtextbox.leave` event. Otherwise `MouseClick` is not a bad idea

Comment: Thank so much.Visual Studio has much flexibilities!

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?